window.open returning null in firefox browser devtools
junior coder learning how to web hack
was using the devtools console in firefox browser, typed both in the stackoverflow main page:
samenewwindow = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com');
responded null
window.open('https://stackoverflow.com');
also null
tried the same code in chrome browser, both worked well.
is firefox not available to use the console to open a new window or sort of something?
